# I want select days in months and count in four time ranges group by days

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

The problem is with range 'THREE', to count from 10 pm till 06 am next day, result to be in previous day, i have this query who give me wrong data report,
any solutions please.

```
select TRUNC (A.time)+06/24,
       count (distinct B.code)as FOUR,
       count(case when to_char(A.time,'HH24:MI:SS') between '06:00:00'
                                                        and '14:00:00'
                  then A.sn end) as ONE,
       count(case when to_char(A.time,'HH24:MI:SS') between '14:00:00'
                                                        and '22:00:00'
                  then A.sn end) as TWO,
       count(case when A.time between TO_DATE ('10:00:00 PM', 'hh:mi:ss AM')
                                  and TO_DATE ('10:00:00 PM', 'hh:mi:ss AM')+6/24
                  then A.sn end) as THREE
from   B
inner join A
  on B.bol_id = A.bol_id
where  B.group = '9'
and    A.time between '01-JUN-18 06:00:00' and '25-JUN-18 06:00:00'
GROUP BY TRUNC (A.time)
```

i want structure be like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxbu6.png)

Comment: Please post sample input, expected output and make sure you post them as plain text and not an image or a link to an image.

Comment: Here you find  something on [ask] and how to build a [mcve] that can be useful to improve your question

Comment: Please don't use ALLCAPS in titles, it's considered the same as SHOUTING and rude.

Comment: I correct the titles, thank you

Comment: Do not post data images. Write it here as code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the `GROUP BY TRUNC (A.time)` - this says to start the window for each row/day at midnight, and end at 11:59 the following night. But you want it from 6am on the current day to 5:59 the next morning. So you want to `GROUP BY TRUNC(A.time - 6/24)` - that way 5:59 this morning will be counted as yesterday, and 5:59 tomorrow will be counted as today.

Then you can modify your case `THREE` to be:

```
count(case when to_char(A.time,'HH24:MI:SS') > '22:00:00'
             or to_char(A.time,'HH24:MI:SS') < '06:00:00'
           then A.sn end) as THREE
```

Give it a try and let us know if you have any issues.

```
select TRUNC(A.time-(6/24)),
       count (distinct B.code)as FOUR,
       count(case when to_char(A.time,'HH24:MI:SS') between '06:00:00'
                                                        and '14:00:00'
                  then A.sn end) as ONE,
       count(case when to_char(A.time,'HH24:MI:SS') between '14:00:00'
                                                        and '22:00:00'
                  then A.sn end) as TWO,
       count(case when to_char(A.time,'HH24:MI:SS') > '22:00:00'
                     or to_char(A.time,'HH24:MI:SS') < '06:00:00'
                   then A.sn end) as THREE
from   B
inner join A
  on B.bol_id = A.bol_id
where  B.group = '9'
and    A.time between '01-JUN-18 06:00:00' and '25-JUN-18 06:00:00'
GROUP BY TRUNC(A.time-(6/24))
```

You might also want to change your cases from `between` to `> and <=`. `between X and Y` includes both end values, so any events happening at precisely 2 PM would be double-counted as both ONE and TWO.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to fix the first line.